# Xamarin.iOS Private API LSApplicationWorkspace

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

How can I use code below in Xamarin.iOS project or how to use iOS private API in Xamarin C# ? Best regards.

```
Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
NSObject * workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:@selector(defaultWorkspace)];
BOOL isopen = [workspace performSelector:@selector(openApplicationWithBundleID:) withObject:@"com.apple.mobilesafari"];
```

Comment: This might interest you: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/objective-c_selectors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSObject LSApplicationWorkspace_class = new NSObject(Class.GetHandle("LSApplicationWorkspace"));
NSObject workspace = LSApplicationWorkspace_class.PerformSelector(new Selector("defaultWorkspace"));
var isOpen = workspace.PerformSelector(new Selector("openApplicationWithBundleID:"), new NSString("com.apple.mobilesafari"));
```